Extracting spoken audio samples from ShortArray in Android Studio
I'm working on an audio processing feature in Android Studio where I'm extracting audio samples as a ShortArray from a user's voice command. However, I'm having trouble analyzing these samples to identify and isolate only the sections where speech was detected, excluding silence or background noise.
Does anyone know of a library or class that can analyze these audio samples and detect the segments with spoken audio? Any suggestions on how to approach this or resources that could help would be greatly appreciated!
Note: I'm using Kaldi, with a sample rate of 16000F, and I'm open to solutions in either Java or Kotlin.
I've tried implementing a custom class called TreatAudio, which compares segments of my audio samples and attempts to recognize a specific phrase within those segments. However, the results have been very inconsistent, often returning false without recognizing anything. Here’s a simplified version of the code I’m using:
public class TreatAudio {
private String control = "";

public boolean extract(short[] samples, Model model, float sampleRate, String phraseRecognized) {
    Recognizer rec = new Recognizer(model, sampleRate);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (!control.equals(phraseRecognized)) {
            rec.acceptWaveForm(samples, samples.length);
            String result= rec.getResult();
            String cleanedResult= result.replaceAll(".*\"partial\"\\s*:\\s*\"(.*?)\".*", "$1").trim();
            if (!cleanedResult.isEmpty() && cleanedResult.contains(phraseRecognized)) {
                control = phraseRecognized;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}

}
This approach has been unreliable, as it often fails to recognize the phrase even when spoken clearly.
Does anyone know of a better method or library that could help analyze the samples and detect segments of spoken audio more accurately? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you in advance!
